# python variable to a static string

Tags: python

I want to turn a Python string into a function that return True if the argument equals that string.
Here's my code:

```
In: x='foo'
In: (lambda c: c==x)('foo')
Out: True
In: x=lambda c: c==x
In: x('foo')
Out: False
```

I tried to use x[:] and x.__repr_(), but they failed as well.

I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is fine. But after

`x=lambda c: c==x`

you have overwritten the value of x, so `x('foo')` evaluates to

`'foo' == (lambda c: c==x)`

which is obviously False.

Comment: One fix is to set `x = lambda c, x=x: c == x` to force the value of `x` in the body of the function to be the string at the time the function is *defined*.

Answer (score 1):

You are replacing the `x` variable by assigning it to a lambda. If you want to test that, just `print(x)` and you will see the issue. Just change the variable name.

```
static_string = "foo"
x = lambda c: c==static_string
assert(x("foo"))
assert(not x("bar"))
```